# Are code-only questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was browsing through the [beginner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag and saw [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48388/restaurant-app-models). It looks functional and is certainly review-able, but OP posted absolutely nothing besides the code. No hint about what it does, or what OP expected from the review. That feels off-topic to me, but I don't know what I would categorize it as.

1. Are code only questions off-topic?
2. If so, what do we categorize them as?
3. Should they only be flagged as low quality?

I would call it "Unclear what you're asking", but by default, aren't people asking for a Code Review?

**Note:** OP has not been seen since [May 7th 2014](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40871/michelle-glauser). I don't think she's coming back.

Comment: [This](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/790/should-a-post-with-no-specific-questions-imply-a-general-review) may also be similar.

Comment: Similar? I'd call it a duplicate. I swear I looked first.

Comment: I was a little hesitant, especially because it doesn't address the third question.

Comment: I was hesitant to even put that in there @Jamal. I've personally never understood why Low Quality is even there. All questions being flagged/close voted are by definition low quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are code only questions off-topic?

No, not by default, and neither the Help Center nor the close reasons specifically state that code-only questions are off-topic.  Others can still ask questions to flesh out any issues with the code, which will help determine if it *is* off-topic.

> Should they only be flagged as low quality?

No, they should not be flagged automatically, especially as Low Quality.  This flag would only be viable if the post makes *absolutely no sense* (such as gibberish) or is just too poorly-written to edit.  In general, this flag should best be used if a post needs to be *deleted* (where Spam/Offensive flags do not apply), not simply closed.

In conclusion, ask the OP for clarification if you need more information, or if you suspect that the code may not work.  If nothing is done, then it can be closed as *unclear what you're asking*.  You may also downvote it if you dislike it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the Low Quality post. I do believe we should discourage the behavior. Downvoting questions like this is probably the appropriate thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that code-only questions are off-topic. However, a question that consists solely of a huge code dump without context could be closed as "Unclear what you are asking" — assuming that it really isn't clear what the intention of the code is.

Comment: In particular case, the docstrings are considered part of the description. If a reader doesnt bother to look at that and just goes on rampage "ey that is just code... close it..." well that is reader's fault.